# formData - sending the form's fields?

Tags: javascript

I have a form:

```
<form id="content-add-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
//form elements
```

In JS I am submitting the form by:

```
$("#content-add-form").submit(function(e) {
```

I'm using formData to add files from JS. My issue is, along with the files, I would also like to send the form's fields.

I have done this:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#content-add-form"));
```

But the fields are not sent. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why not use `$("#inputID").val();` ??

Comment: Because I dont want to run through every field in my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FormData constructor takes a DOM element, not a jQuery element. Use the get() method in order to get the DOM element:

```
new FormData($('#content-add-form').get(0));
```